# Adding custom card information to Payment Request

Tags: javascript, payment-request-api

I want to implement [payment request api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Payment_Request_API) to my website.

Payment request popup lists users saved cards associated with mobile phone and Google&Apple accounts.

I also want to put custom credit cards into that popup because we have already implemented save credit cards feature and it is been working for a while. I couldn't find any support for it reading documentations. Is it possible?

Expected to have a support like

```
var supportedInstruments = [{
 supportedMethods: 'basic-card',
 data: {
   supportedNetworks: ['visa', 'mastercard'],
   supportedTypes: ['credit', 'debit']
 },
  customCards: [{ //Custom credit cards
    number: '000000000000000',
    owner: 'John Doe'
  }]
}];

var details = {
  total: {label: 'Donation', amount: {currency: 'USD', value: '65.00'}},
  displayItems: [
    {
      label: 'Original donation amount',
      amount: {currency: 'USD', value: '65.00'}
    }
  ],
  shippingOptions: [
    {
      id: 'standard',
      label: 'Standard shipping',
      amount: {currency: 'USD', value: '0.00'},
      selected: true
    }
  ]
};
var request = new PaymentRequest(supportedInstruments, details);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no such feature nor proposal as far as I know, though I have heard similar requests in the past.

One work around would be to implement a merchant specific payment method using [the Payment Handler API](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/payments/payment-apps-developer-guide/web-payment-apps). This API allows you to provide your own payment method. You can consume it by yourself and allow third parties to do so.